# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).imagesLoaded is not a function Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with the Post Grid and Filter Wordpress Plugin.

On the Wordpress backend it works but on frontend i get:

```
pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:185 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).imagesLoaded is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:185)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
at pgafu_post_filter_init (pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:179)
at pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:6
at pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:171
(anonymous) @ pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:185
each @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2
each @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2
pgafu_post_filter_init @ pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:179
(anonymous) @ pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:6
(anonymous) @ pgafu-public.js?ver=1.4:171
```

this all is on the Page [Website](http://website.xn--hllenkremer-thb.de/containerbau/absetzmulden/)
the Plugin is before the page bottom under "REFERENZEN"

Can anyone help me please?

Regards
Alex